# insert single and double inverted comma in between number and char value in shell

Tags: shell, sed

I have a data file like this

```
12,34,45,Po_yiu
```

My expected output is like (in shell script.)

```
'12','34','45','Po_yiu'`
```

For this I have tried

```
cat testing.sh | sed -e "s/^.*$/'&'/g"
```

but unable to find exact output.

Comment: `^.*$` or even just `.*` will consume entire input line, why did you expect it to magically match fields based on `,` character?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew good spot on duplicate question, but there's a simpler answer that's missing in that thread, perhaps starting spaces made things complex

Answer (score 2):

Hope this help. 
Multiple sed in one command.

```
sed "s/.*/'&'/g; s/,/','/g" filename

'12','34','45','Po_yiu'
```

Comment: you can also use `sed "s/[^,]*/'&'/g"`